# du excluding hard links possible?

Tags: du

I'm trying to determine how big a cloned Git repository is from a local file system. It creates hard links for some but not all files. How can I determine the disk usage of it? The best I can come up with is "du -a" right now with the original and again with the clone to determine the difference, since each hard linked file will be counted only once. Ideally, I would just run du on the clone and count each hard linked file zero times.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of du is not to count hard linked files several times.

You may enable it to count hard linked files as many times as it linked with `-l` option:

I have 3 links to the file of 32 Kb.

```
$ du 
36  .


$ du -l
100 .
```

The extra 4 Kb in both cases is the size of directory itself